# Find inverse Laplace transform for $coth$ function

Tags: laplace-transform

Find inverse Laplace transform for the function 
$$
F(p)=\sqrt{\frac{p+1}{p^2+3p+1}}\,  {\rm coth}\left( \sqrt{\frac{p^2+3p+1}{p+1}}\right).
$$
In the book Prudnikov & ...  I have found two formulas for 
$$
\frac{1}{p} {\rm coth}(p)
$$
and for 
$$
F(\sqrt{p})
$$

but I still can find the solution.  Any ideas to do it?

Comment: I think the problem here is that the ILT will ultimately be expressed in terms of other integrals that are fairly difficult to evaluate.